# JavaScript strange notation of class definition

Tags: javascript, class

It's working fine, but I do not understand the meaning of line #4 and #5.

```
import path from 'path';
class SomeClass {
  strange1;
  strange2;

  constructor(strange1) {
    this.strange1 = strange1;
    this.strange2 = path.join(__dirname, '..');
  }

  get somePath() {
    let result
    if (this.strange1) {
      result = path.join(this.strange2, '..'),
    } else {
      result = undefined
    }
    return result
  }
}

export default SomeClass
```

What meaning of call strange1 and strange2 in top of class definition?

Comment: You should include the actual code you don't understand rather than your reinterpretation of the code. Preferably as a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by "string #2 and #3"? Do you mean lines 2 and 3? This looks like TypeScript. ES6 classes do not permit the declaration of instance variables, which is what `strange1;` is.